# Audio continues playing on Phonegap when receiving a call

Tags: cordova, audio, background, call, media

I'm creating a Radio App, which works fine on iOS using HTML5.
To do it on Android I need to use Phonegap Media resource.
I'm able to play the streaming and MP3s files, even in background/suspended mode, but when I receive a call the audio continues playing. This is a big problem.
Shouldn't Android shut down the audio on a call? (call = priority on iOS).
I'm using the online build for Phonegap (http://build.phonegap.com) so, I cannot use any Java external plugin for Phonegap (like https://github.com/devgeeks/PhoneListener).
There is some Phonegap events (startcallbutton/endcallbutton), but not supported for Android (I really dont know why).

Anybody has a solution? Tanks!

Comment: Any update for Phonegap/Cordova 3.0/3.1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the READ_PHONE_STATE permission in your AndroidManifest.xml file, if its not there already, otherwise the app won't know if you are receiving a call or not. You will also need an addEventListener for an onPause and onResume method to tell the stream to pause and play when you get a call and when you hang up, respectively.